# Recommended approach for linq to sql serialization for simple json and mvc

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, model-view-controller, json, serialization

I have cascading drop down lists in a .net mvc view and am using JQuery onchange to pull the next drop down list using a json response.  The problem comes in where iI get a circular reference when trying to serialize the linq to sql response.

I understand why it is happening, its because I have the buyer -> contracts and contract -> buyer relationships which will be circular when serialized.

I am wondering what the recommended solution is.  Should I create a new json specific object and map the fields I need for the response?

Is there a way of ignoring the relationships when serializing and just returning this table (i dont need any relationships as its just a drop down list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hit this exact same problem recently and it appears there is no real elegant solution to this short of using something like [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) (which I've not tried myself but is supposed to not throw the circular reference error).

The solution I ended up using (for my tiny project) was to set the referenced entity to null prior to serialisation.  This could get old very quickly for larger projects which I where Json.NET would come in handy I think.

Answer (score 0):

Make the child relationship 'interal' rather than public in the DBML.

See Rick Strahl's post for more information.
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Sep/02/LINQ-to-SQL-and-Serialization